# C How Do I Print The Elements of an Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, xcode, loops

although the title seems like I am simply printing an array, it is not quite that.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char planets[7][7]={"Mercury", "  Venus", "   Mars", "Jupiter", " Saturn", " Uranus", "Neptune"};
    float weights[7]={(200*37.8*0.01),(200*90.7*0.01),(200*37.7*0.01),(200*236.0*0.01),(200*91.6*0.01),(200*88.9*0.01),(200*112.0*0.01)};
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        printf("%s: %3.1f\n",planets[i], weights[i]);
    }
}
```

My goal here is to print

```
Mercury: xxx.x
  Venus: xxx.x
```

etc.

However, my code prints this:

```
Mercury  Venus   MarsJupiter Saturn UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 75.6
  Venus   MarsJupiter Saturn UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 181.4
   MarsJupiter Saturn UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 75.4
Jupiter Saturn UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 472.0
 Saturn UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 183.2
 UranusNeptune\365\277\357\376: 177.8
Neptune\365\277\357\376: 224.0
```

What is that, why is it printing the whole of my array the whole time, what are the numbers like \365\277\357\376 doing at the end? I am just so confused.

Comment: Although you shouldn't really post two (unrelated) questions as one … the second argument to `fopen` specifies what *mode* to open the file in: [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not assigning enough 'space' in your `planets` array to hold the given names!

For example, the string literal, `"Mercury"` is actually an array of **eight** `char` elements: the seven letters ***plus the `NUL` terminator*** (all strings in `C` should have this 'zero-byte' terminator signal and the compiler will automatically add one to any given string literal/constant).

Simply change your `planets[7][7]` to `planets[7][8]` and the code will work.

EDIT: What you are seeing in your output is an example of the dreaded **Undefined Behaviour**!  Because there is no `NUL` terminator in each string, the `printf` call keeps printing extra characters after the 'end' of the planet's name, until it finds a `char` that is zero. Your seven planet names are in *contiguous* memory, so, on each loop, the `printf` 'overruns' into the next planet's name. After reaching the end of "Neptune" it then starts interpreting memory that was not defined as `char` data as individual bytes - and neither you nor I can really predict what such memory values will be: hence Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Make it `char planets[7][8]`. When you set array size to exact number of letters in strings there is no place left for `null` symbol. So `printf` do not know where your strings end.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, difficult to type on a phone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work:

```c
char* planets[7]={"Mercury", "  Venus", "   Mars", "Jupiter", " Saturn", " Uranus", "Neptune"};
```

Comment: Although your code *will* work, it is generally better, when posting an answer on Stack Overflow, to offer at least a brief explanation as to *why* it works and/or why the OP's code doesn't work.